# Custom Loss Function: logits and targets must have the same shape ((?, 1) vs (45000,))

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

My model predicts everything as 0 in a binary classifier. In total we have 4000 true's and 41000 false's. Therefore we're trying to make a custom loss function.

The error I receive is:

(logits.get_shape(), targets.get_shape()))

ValueError: logits and targets must have the same shape ((?, 1) vs (45000,))

The code looks like this:

```
combined = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([modelRNN.output, modelCNN.output])

final_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')(combined) #ff kijken of dit slim is
final_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(final_dense)

final_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[modelCNN.input, modelRNN.input], outputs=final_dense)

targets = match_train
logits = final_dense
pos_weight = (45000 - 4539) / 4539


custom_loss = tf.nn.weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    targets,
    logits,
    pos_weight,
    )


final_model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                    loss=custom_loss,
                    metrics=['accuracy'])
```

the shape of the initial arrays are:

```
modelCNN = (45000, 28, 28, 1) float64
modelRNN = (45000, 93, 13) float64
labels = (45000,1) boolean
```

The problem was partly solved with the code in the comments.
I now receive an error that I didn't had before. It says:

```
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.

  File "<ipython-input-6-42327e5a4b50>", line 3, in <module>
    metrics=['accuracy'])

  File "C:\Users\Tijev\Anaconda3\envs\tfp3.6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\checkpointable\base.py", line 442, in _method_wrapper
    method(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Tijev\Anaconda3\envs\tfp3.6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 215, in compile
    loss = loss or {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape your labels as a 2D tensor.

```
targets = np.asarray(match_train).astype('float32').reshape((-1,1))
```

Source: [Tensorflow estimator ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((?, 1) vs (?,))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851558/tensorflow-estimator-valueerror-logits-and-labels-must-have-the-same-shape?rq=1)

Comment: This seems to work partially. I now receive another error. I edited my post. Could you perhaps take a look at that? It's an error that I didn't had before I created the custom loss function.

Comment: You should open a separate question for that, instead of modifying the question that you asked, since you're asking about a different error now. Generally, the issues seems to be mixing Numpy/Python with Tensorflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49177169/tensorflow-typeerror-using-a-tf-tensor-as-a-python-bool-is-not-allowed This might help give you perspective into the issue, but otherwise, I'd strongly recommend googling the error and seeing what comes up. Stackoverflow encourages trying to look stuff up before asking questions, to reduce redundancies. Good luck!